# Match occurrences of a character before a control character, match zero if control character not present

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm

I am working on functionality to allow a user to specify a "wildcarded" path for items in a folder hierarchy and an associated action that will be performed when an item matches that path. e.g.:

```
    Path         Action
    -----------  -------
 1. $/foo/*/baz  include
 2. $/foo/bar/*  exclude
```

Now with the example above, an item at `$/foo/bar/baz` would match both actions. Given this I want to provide a crude score of specificity of the wildcarded path, which will be based on the "depth" the first wildcard character occurs at. The path with the most depth will win. Importantly, only `*` bounded by forward slashes (`/*/`) is allowed as a wildcard (except when at the end then `/*`) and any number could be specified at various points in the path.

**TL;DR;**

So, I think a regex to count the number of forward slashes prior to the first `*` is the way to go. However for a number of reasons, where there is no wildcard in the path the match of forward slashes will be zero. I have got to the following negative lookbehind:

```
 (?<!\*.*)/
```

which works fine when there are wildcards (e.g. 2 forward slash matches for path #1 above and 3 for #2), but when there is no wildcard it naturally matches all forward slashes. I am sure it is a simple step to match none but due to rusty regex skills I am stuck.

Ideally from an academic point of view I'd like to see if a single regex could capture this, however bonus points offered for a more elegant solution to the problem!

Comment: Before calling the regex, could you check the string for an asterisk? `if(path.Contains("*")) DoRegex();`

Comment: Absolutely. Sorry, should have stated this is more of an academic question to see if it can be done in a single expression.

Comment: Arghh, just saw that you were after a more academic answer rather than a solution to the issue. Well, I should have concentrated on that :-(

Comment: It's all good @Renaud. +1. I like the solution and it may be better than a pure regex route! Thank-you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be one way to do it:

```
match = Regex.Match(subject, 
    @"^       # Start of string
    (         # Match and capture in group number 1...
     [^*/]*   #  any number of characters except slashes or asterisks
     /        #  followed by a slash
    )*        # zero or more times.
    [^*/]*    # Match any additional non-slash/non-asterisk characters.
    \*        # Then match an asterisk", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Now this regex fails to match if there is no asterisk in the `subject` string (score of `0`). If the regex matches, you can be sure that there is at least one asterisk in it.

The clever thing now is that .NET regexes, unlike most other regex flavors, actually can count how many times a repeated capturing group has matched (most other regex engines simply discard that information), which allows us to determine the number of slashes before the first asterisk in the string.

That information can be found in

```
match.Groups[1].Captures.Count
```

(Of course this means that "no slashes before the first asterisk" and "no asterisk at all" would both get the score `0`, which appears to be what you're asking for in your question, but I'm not sure why this would make sense)

Answer (score 1):

A way that would approach the task:

1. Validate all test paths (make sure they are valid and contain either `\*\` or end by `*`).
2. Use a sorted collection to keep track of the test paths and associated actions.
3. Sort the collection based on the position of the wildcard in the string.
4. Test the item against each path in the sorted collection.
   You can replace the `*` in the string by `.*?` to use it in a regex.
5. Stop at the first match and return the associated action, otherwise continue with the next test in the collection.

A quick test implementation of some of the above:

```
void Main()
{
    // Define some actions to test and add them to a collection
    var ActionPaths = new List<ActionPath>() {
        new ActionPath() {TestPath = "/foo/*/baz",   Action = "include"},
        new ActionPath() {TestPath = "/foo/bar/*",   Action = "exclude"},
        new ActionPath() {TestPath = "/foo/doo/boo", Action = "exclude"},
    };
    // Sort the list of actions based on the depth of the wildcard
    ActionPaths.Sort();

    // the path for which we are trying to find the corresponding action
    string PathToTest = "/foo/bar/baz";

    // Test all ActionPaths from the top down until we find something
    var found = default(ActionPath);
    foreach (var ap in ActionPaths) {
        if (ap.IsMatching(PathToTest)) {
            found = ap;
            break;
        }
    }

    // At this point, we have either found an Action, or nothing at all
    if (found != default(ActionTest)) {
        // Found an Action!
    } else {
        // Found nothing at all :-(
    }
}

// Hold and Action Test
class ActionPath : IComparable<ActionPath>
{
    public string TestPath;
    public string Action;

    // Returns true if the given path matches the TestPath
    public bool IsMatching(string path) {
        var t = TestPath.Replace("*",".*?");
        return Regex.IsMatch(path, "^" + t + "$");
    }

    // Implements IComparable<T>
    public int CompareTo(ActionPath other) {
       if (other.TestPath == null) return 1;
       var ia = TestPath.IndexOf("*");
       var ib = other.TestPath.IndexOf("*");
       if (ia < ib) return 1;       
       if (ia > ib) return -1;
       return 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for regular expressions here.

With LINQ it's a 2-liner:

```
string s = "$/foo/bar/baz";
var asteriskPos = s.IndexOf('*');  // will be -1 if there is no asterisk
var slashCount = s.Where((c, i) => c == '/' && i < asteriskPos).Count();
```